# React (Gatsby) - npm package Elevio problems

Tags: reactjs, npm, elevio

I am trying to implement Elevio into my React project and am following the documentation here https://api-docs.elevio.help/en/articles/90-how-to-integrate-elevio-into-react

After running `npm i` and inserting this piece of code

```
<div>
    <Elevio accountId="account-id" />
</div>
```

my project crashes and gives me this error

> Module not found: Error: package path ./lib/react is not exported from package

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing from `package.json`. It worked for me.

Reference: https://api-docs.elevio.help/en/articles/89

Comment: Can you give me a bit more detail about how you did it? And also what does your package.json look like?

Comment: Hope this helps. https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-cache-wyk2f?file=/src/components/App.js

Comment: Heya Kristian from Elevio here, if @MuhtasimUlfatTanmoy solution doesn't work let me know and I can help.

Comment: Hey Kristian, yea I might need your help. I have compared my package.json and the Elevio init code block with @MuhtasimUlfatTanmoy and I can't seem to find any discrepancies.

Comment: Update: I just tested it with a new base template with ```npx create-react-app``` followed by ```npm i elevio``` and it worked! I'm not too sure why it doesn't work for my current project however, where I went through the exact same steps.

Comment: Update 2: I think I have discovered what the problem is. When creating a new React project using ```npm init gatsby``` and then installing Elevio, it throws the same error leading me to believe that this is a error on Gatsby's side.

Comment: Hi Kristian, did Elevio build special APIs for Gatsby integration? We keep having issues like Yang has asked when trying to embed Elevio into Gatsby. Or is it not recommended to integrate Elevio with Gatsby? Thanks